# if statement in sql

Tags: oracle

SQL Script

i would like to use "IF" statement where output is greater than 365 days then specific row should be updated as "Yes" else "No"

if ( to_date('04/06/2015','dd/mm/rrrr')- lodg_date ) > 365 then 
"Yes" 
else 
"No" 
end if ; 
please advise

Comment: The db is...? Pick one.

Comment: Are you looking for a `SELECT` query or an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: if value is greater than 365 between two days , i want to update as Yes else NO against each record

Comment: i am executing query in SQL developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support an `IF` statement (outside of PL/SQL blocks)

Your question lists tags for three different RDBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server), and each one does things a little bit differently.

In Oracle, you can subtract two `DATE` expressions and get the difference as a value in days (whole and fractional.)

You can use a `CASE` expression to do a conditional test, and return a value depending on the result of the test.

For developing and testing expressions, we usually do that in a SELECT statement, e.g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TO_DATE('04/06/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')-t.lodg_date > 365
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END AS over_a_year
     , t.lodg_date
  FROM mytable t
```

If you want to perform an update operation, to update all rows in a table, to set a column to the return from that expression,

```
 UPDATE mytable t 
    SET t.my_over_a_year_yes_no_column 
      = CASE WHEN TO_DATE('04/06/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')-t.lodg_date > 365
             THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
        END
```

---

NOTE: The `TO_DATE` function and the the "subtract two `DATE` expressions" pattern works in Oracle. But this won't work in other databases. Other databases may allow string literals to be enclosed in double quotes, but Oracle does not. String literals, like `'Yes'` and `'No'` have to enclosed in single quotes. Double quotes are reserved for enclosing identifiers. And `IF` is not a valid SQL statement in Oracle. It can be used in the context of a PL/SQL block, but that's for control flow in a PL/SQL program; it's not a SQL statement that's submitted to the database.

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN TO_DATE('04/06/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')-t.lodg_date > 365
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END AS over_a_year
     , t.lodg_date
  FROM mytable t     worked perfectly thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF` as per the below:

SQL Server https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

MySQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

PostgreSQL http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff